# RedisTemplate get list with value operation

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis, lettuce

It is possible to get back a List of Objects using RedisTemplate get value operation?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
public class RedisDao {
  private final RedisTemplate<String, List<Object>> redisTemplate;

  public void saveCustomObjects(List<CustomObject> customObjects, key) {
    redisTemplate.opsForValue.set(key, Arrays.asList(customObjects.toArray()));
  }
 public List<CustomObject> getCustomObjects(String key) {
   return redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key) //This returns an arrayList where the values are LinkedHashMap
 }
}
```

RedisTemplate configuration:

```
maven dependencies: spring-data-redis, lettuce-core
....
redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())
redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer())
...
```

Comment: I would check if Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<CustomObject> is a better choice instead of GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.

Comment: I have the same result with Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RedisDao {
  private final RedisTemplate<String, byte[]> redisTemplate;

  public void saveCustomObjects(List<CustomObject> customObjects, key) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    redisTemplate.opsForValue.set(key, objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(customObjects);
  }
 public List<CustomObject> getCustomObjects(String key) {
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
   return objectMapper.readValue(redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key), new TypeReference<>() {});
 }
}
```

RedisTemplate configuration:

```
redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())
redisTemplate.setEnableDefaultSerializer(false);
```

This works but doesn't seems like a good practice.